# Why won't my scatterplot legend in matplotlib render properly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am a bit new to Python and am much more used to programming in R and using ggplot for visual. I am trying to complete a visual in matplotlib, but can't seem to figure out the plot legend. Below is the code. X and Y are numeric types, while column z is a string.

I expected a graph with a legend where 0 is red and 1 is black, but only the legend title appears.

```
plt_data = pd.DataFrame(plt_data)
plt.figure()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
labs = ["1", "0"]
colors = {'1':'black', '0':'red'}
scatter = ax.scatter(plt_data['x'], plt_data['y'], c = plt_data['z'].map(colors))
legend1 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(), loc="upper left", title="z")
ax.add_artist(legend1)
plt.show()
```

And here is the plot image

[image: img]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as this issue doesn't seem like it should be too difficult, but I am struggling to find a solution that works

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom colour map, in this case, a list of colours:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

c_RB = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(["red", "black"])
```

Now, for the scatter colouring, think of "c" as the data that will categorize each point (so, your "z" column). And "cmap" will be what dictates the colour for each category.

So:

```
x = [1, 2]
y = [2, 3]
z = [1, 0]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c = z, cmap = c_RB )

legend1 = ax.legend(*scatter.legend_elements(), loc="upper left", title="z")

plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

You don't need to call add_artist(), unless you are actually planning to add several legends.